# Delete selected row via database grid viewer

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, ms-access-2010, delete-row

i need to be able to delete a row and its content via a datagrid viewer, the current code i have written only deletes the contents of row 0 and i cannot get it to do so at a selected row.

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Dim dataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DataTable As New DataTable
    Dim DataSet As New DataSet
    Try

        DataSet.Tables.Add(DataTable)
        Connection.Open()
        dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Students", Connection)
        dataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)
        DataTable.Rows(0).BeginEdit()
        DataTable.Rows(0).Delete()
        DataTable.Rows(0).EndEdit()
        Dim Commandbuilder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter)
        dataAdapter.Update(DataTable)
        dgrStudentDatabaseViewer.DataSource = DataTable.DefaultView
        Connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Connection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DataTable.Rows(0).Delete()` you have it hardcoded to delete row(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code you can delete current selected row:

```
DataTable.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).BeginEdit()
DataTable.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Delete()
DataTable.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).EndEdit()
```